# How to reduce time to check whether an excel cell is locked or not?

Tags: python, excel, xls, xlrd

I am working on an excel workbook.

I want to put some data from a `.txt` file in different worksheets.
Before inserting the data, I want to check whether the cell is `locked` or not.

I am using a `python` script to check whether the cell is locked or not.

In detail I am using the `isLocked` function of `com`(`com` is used for excel operations by `python`).

In one particular worksheet I got 30-40 locked cells, which is taking 20-30 minutes in total, to check the lock status.

Is there a better way, to check the lock status in order to decrease the time needed?

Comment: this is old question. Did you find in the meantime a solution? maybe with xlwings?

Comment: Almost 9 years old question... I no longer deal with excel.